Next.js Sellix embed modal shows white background in next-themes dark mode despite transparent CSS
I'm experiencing an issue with a Sellix embed modal in my Next.js (app router) application. When the modal is opened in dark mode, it displays a solid white background, despite my efforts to make it transparent. Here are the key details:

Environment:

Next.js application
Using Tailwind CSS for styling
Next-themes' ThemeProvider for Dark mode
Sellix' custom checkout modal


Issue:

In light mode, the Sellix modal background is correctly transparententer image description here
In dark mode, a solid white background appears behind the modal content


Expected Behavior:
Upon clicking "purchase" button below, a Sellix modal should appear with its normally styled "blurred" background on top of the page's existing content, in both light and dark modes, allowing the underlying page content to be visible.


After "Purchase" press (Light mode enabled) - Background appears, blurred. This exact behavior should happen for dark or light mode, regardless.

Actual Behavior:
In dark mode, a solid white background appears behind the Sellix modal content, on top of the underlying page.

Before "Purchase" press (Dark mode enabled) 
After "Purchase" press (Dark mode enabled) - Solid white background.

Attempted Solutions:

Applied background: transparent !important; to Sellix-related elements in CSS
Used both data-sellix-css attribute and a separate CSS file for custom styles
Implemented media queries and class-based dark mode styles
Added !important to background styles for Sellix elements
Ensured color-scheme: dark; is set for dark mode



I've tried various CSS overrides and inspected the elements using browser developer tools, but I can't seem to identify the source of this white background in dark mode. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Relevant Code:

layout.tsx:

import { ViewTransitions } from 'next-view-transitions';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@/context/theme-provider';
import './globals.css'; // Ensure global styles are included
import Head from 'next/head';
import Script from "next/script";

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
        <Script src="https://cdn.sellix.io/static/js/embed.js" strategy="beforeInteractive"/>
        <body className="bg-white dark:bg-black antialiased h-full w-full">
        <ThemeProvider attribute='class' disableTransitionOnChange defaultTheme='dark'>
            <ViewTransitions>{children}</ViewTransitions>
        </ThemeProvider>
        </body>
        </html>
    );
}






.../Test2/page.tsx (test page im using for this):

     const Test2 = () => {
        return (
            <div style={{
                display: 'flex',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                height: '100vh',
                flexDirection: 'column',
                textAlign: 'center'
            }}>
                <button
                    data-sellix-product="64aeff68a36da"
                    type="submit"
                    alt="Buy Now with sellix.io"
                    style={{padding: '10px 20px', fontSize: '16px', cursor: 'pointer', margin: '20px 0'}}
                >
                    Purchase
                </button>
    
            </div>
        );
    };
    
    export default Test2;


global.css:

@import "./prism.css";

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

/* globals.css */


:root {
  --foreground-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --background-start-rgb: 214, 219, 220;
  --background-end-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --foreground-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --background-start-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
    --background-end-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  }
}

html, body {
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Ensure no horizontal scrolling */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.25);
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.25);
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
}

.animate-pulse-custom {
  animation: pulse 2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.6, 2) infinite;
}

@layer utilities {
  .text-balance {
    text-wrap: balance;
  }
}



/* Rotate Animation */
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.icon-rotate {
  animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
}

/* Pulse Animation */
@keyframes pulse {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
}

.icon-pulse {
  animation: pulse 2s ease-in-out infinite;
}

/* Tada Animation */
@keyframes tada {
  0%, 20%, 100% {
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0);
  }
  5% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateY(0); /* Slightly smaller and raised up */
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateY(-3px) rotate(-4deg); /* Bigger and start wiggle */
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateY(-3px) rotate(4deg); /* Continue wiggle */
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateY(-3px) rotate(-4deg); /* Continue wiggle */
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateY(-3px) rotate(4deg); /* Continue wiggle */
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateY(-3px) rotate(-4deg); /* Continue wiggle */
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateY(-3px) rotate(3deg); /* Continue wiggle */
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0); /* Back to normal size */
  }
}

.icon-tada {
  animation: tada 3s ease-in-out infinite; /* Adjusted duration for periodic effect */
}

.hide-default-cursor {
  cursor: none;
}

/* Add this at the end of your globals.css */
.custom-range input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  display: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.custom-range input[type='range']::-moz-range-thumb {
  display: none;
}

.custom-range input[type='range']::-ms-thumb {
  display: none;
}


tailwind.config.ts:

import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";
const {
  default: flattenColorPalette,
} = require("tailwindcss/lib/util/flattenColorPalette");

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./layouts/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js"
  ],
  darkMode: "class",
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        xs: '580px',
      },
      backgroundImage: {
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
        "gradient-conic":
          "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },
      colors: {
        primary: "#020022",
        muted: "var(--neutral-600)",
        "muted-dark": "var(--neutral-300)",
      },
      animation: {
        scroll:
          "scroll var(--animation-duration, 40s) var(--animation-direction, forwards) linear infinite",
        marquee: "marquee var(--marquee-duration) linear infinite",
        "fade-in": "fade-in 0.5s linear forwards",
        gradient: "gradient 8s linear infinite",
        pulse: "pulse var(--duration) ease-out infinite",

      },
      boxShadow: {
        derek: `0px 0px 0px 1px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.06),
        0px 1px 1px -0.5px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.06),
        0px 3px 3px -1.5px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.06), 
        0px 6px 6px -3px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.06),
        0px 12px 12px -6px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.06),
        0px 24px 24px -12px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.06)`,
        aceternity: `0px 2px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(25,28,33,0.02), 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(25,28,33,0.08)`,
      },
      keyframes: {
        pulse: {
          "0%, 100%": { boxShadow: "0 0 0 0 var(--pulse-color)" },
          "50%": { boxShadow: "0 0 0 8px var(--pulse-color)" },
        },
        gradient: {
          to: {
            backgroundPosition: "var(--bg-size) 0",
          },
        },
        scroll: {
          to: {
            transform: "translate(calc(-50% - 0.5rem))",
          },
        },
        marquee: {
          "100%": {
            transform: "translateY(-50%)",
          },
        },
        "fade-in": {
          from: {
            opacity: "0",
          },
          to: {
            opacity: "1",
          },
        },
        "shine-pulse": {
          "0%": {
            "background-position": "0% 0%",
          },
          "50%": {
            "background-position": "100% 100%",
          },
          to: {
            "background-position": "0% 0%",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [addVariablesForColors, require("@tailwindcss/typography"), require('flowbite/plugin')
  ],
};

function addVariablesForColors({ addBase, theme }: any) {
  let allColors = flattenColorPalette(theme("colors"));
  let newVars = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(allColors).map(([key, val]) => [`--${key}`, val])
  );

  addBase({
    ":root": newVars,
  });
}

export default config;


.sellix-iframe {
    color-scheme: none;
}

Somewhere in the code
